# UIslider increase 10 by 10

Tags: iphone, uislider

I'm making an UISlider and I don't find how to change the selectable values, I would like the only values possible be 10 by 10.
The slider begins at 82 and ends at 362. I want the possible value to be 82,92,102,.....

I've tried different things but I don't find

```
[sliderannonce setValue: [sliderannonce value]+10.0 animated:YES];
```

or

```
sliderannonce.value=10;
```

I've my action here:

```
- (IBAction)changeSliderAnnonce:(id)sender{

 labelSliderAnnonce.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"annonce:%d",(int)sliderannonce.value];

}
```

If you did something like that or you know how to do please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to "cheat" with your idea thanks :D
I started to 8,2 and end to 36,2 and I multiply by 10

```
- (IBAction)changeSliderAnnonce:(id)sender{

    int position= ((int)sliderannonce.value)*10+2;
    labelSliderAnnonce.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"annonce: %d",((int)sliderannonce.value)*10+ 2];


    NSLog(@"valeur de l'enchere: %d",position);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just multiply the value by 10 in your code and add the starting value?

Example : start the slider at 0, end at 28 :

```
int position = 82 + ((int)sliderannonce.value) * 10;
```